# get value in action class

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

how can i get number ID in action? for example

```
class jobActions extends sfActions
{
      public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
      {
        $this->jobeet_jobs = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')
          ->createQuery('a')
          ->where('id = 3')
          ->execute();

        echo $this->jobeet_jobs->getId(); //doesnt work
      }

      public function executeTest(sfWebRequest $request)
      {
         $this->id = $this->jobeet_jobs->getId(); /doesnt work
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is the query even send in a correct syntax to the datebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As execute returns an array of objects, you either need to iterate through them recieving the ids or you use `$this->jobeet_jobs = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')
          ->createQuery('a')
          ->where('id = 3')
          ->fetchOne();`

Comment: As you are using symfony, why don't you use find('3')? This will try to use the primary key and returns only one result, which should fit your needs!

Answer (score 3):

In your `executeIndex` function you retrieve a Doctrine_Collection (a list). Replace `->execute();` with `fetchOne();`

Or you use some of the following handy functions:

```
->find($yourID); // Returns ONE object
->findByColumnnamehere($yourValue); // Returns LIST of objects
->findOneByColumnnamehere($yourValue); // Returns ONE object
```

Comment: make sure that `$yourID` is a primary key. also possible would be `->find(1,2)` (assuming you've got 2 primaries) or `->find(array(1,2))` (returns you a collection where id=1 or id=2)